# how to use .append and .remove in proper way

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

i wonder why my code isn't working properly.

here is my code

```
oTable.$('tr').click(function () {

    $(this).toggleClass('selected');

    var sData = oTable.fnGetData(this);
    //alert( sData[6] );

    if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
        $(this).toggleClass('');

        $('#try').append("<p class='" + sData[6] + "'>" + sData[6] + "</p>");
        $('#price').append("<p class='" + sData[5] + " total'>" + sData[5] + "</p>");
        $('#item').append("<p class='" + sData[4] + "'>" + sData[4] + "</p>");
        $('#model').append("<p class='" + sData[3] + "'>" + sData[3] + "</p>");
        $('#brand').append("<p class='" + sData[2] + "'>" + sData[2] + "</p>");
        $('#pid').append("<p class='" + sData[1] + "'>" + sData[1] + "</p>");
    } else {
        $("p", "#try").remove("." + sData[6]);
        $("p", "#price").remove("." + sData[5]);
        $("p", "#item").remove("." + sData[4]);
        $("p", "#model").remove("." + sData[3]);
        $("p", "#brand").remove("." + sData[2]);
        $("p", "#pid").remove("." + sData[1]);
        // alert ("sad"); 
    }
```

still didn't remove the brand and pid. Need your help guys.

and here is my html code where my jquery do. and these are the divs that will get the value when clicking the tr. in datatable

```
<div id="try" class="try"></div>
                          <div id="price" class="price"></div>
                          <div id="item" class="item"></div>
                          <div id="model" class="model"></div>
                          <div id="brand" class="brand"></div>
                          <div id="pid" class="pid"></div>





                             <table id="example"  cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="display">
                                <thead>
                                  <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>Category</th>
                                    <th>Brand</th>
                                    <th>Model</th>
                                    <th>Item Name</th>
                                    <th>Price</th>
                                    <th>id</th>
                                  </tr>
                               </thead>

                                <tbody>
                                <?php do { ?>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo ++$i;?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row_products['pid']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row_products['brand']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row_products['model']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row_products['item_name_']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row_products['price'];?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row_products['id']; ?></td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <?php } while ($row_products = mysql_fetch_assoc($products)); ?>
                                </tbody>
                             </table>
```

Comment: } else {

$( "p" , "#try").remove( "."+ sData[6]);
$( "p" , "#price").remove( "."+ sData[5]);
$( "p" , "#item").remove( "."+ sData[4]);
$( "p" , "#model").remove( "."+ sData[3]);
$( "p" , "#brand").remove( "."+ sData[2]);
$( "p" , "#pid").remove( "."+ sData[1]);
 //   alert ("sad");
  }

Comment: what are the values in `sData[6]` does the value can have spaces or `[]`

Comment: Can you inspect the created `p` elements to see the class values assigned to them

Comment: i have datatable and i used toggle class . i have many divs and the output when cliking the tr of datatable is to display on div the value of tr and the sData[6] is the number of column and so on.. now i want to remove them when clicking again the same tr.

Comment: Are you trying to remove the elements or the `classes`? To remove a class you would call `$(someSelector).removeClass('classToRemove');` if you want to remove the element it would be `$(someSelector).find('.classToRemove').remove();`

Comment: yeah i want to remove it but what if i have 2 selected tr so it will display 2 sets of sData[6]and so on.... then i click again the one of those selected ro remove it. the output is it will remove all the data in div but i want remove is only one tr. did you get my point?

Comment: Also, `$("p", "#try")` will target all paragraphs **and** the element with the id `try`, you probably jsut want `$("#try")`

Comment: You're probably going to need to create a jsFiddle with an example of your table, clearly describe what action you are taking, what **should happen** , and what happens that is incorrect. Presently, it's difficult to follow what the issue actually is

Comment: FYI,this does nothing `$(this).toggleClass('');`....... without a class specified

Comment: its complicated to make an jsFiddle because i have data in datatable is from my database what's your email i will send the screenshot of what am i doing.

Comment: yeah then i can delete it now.

Comment: please anyone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: i already edited my post so you can see there my html. hope it can help you to analyze what im trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<div class="container">
<div id="try"></div>
                          <div id="price"></div>
                          <div id="item"></div>
                          <div id="model"></div>
                          <div id="brand"></div>
                          <div id="pid"></div>


</div>

                         <table id="example"  cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="display">
                            <thead>
                              <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>Category</th>
                                <th>Brand</th>
                                <th>Model</th>
                                <th>Item Name</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                                <th>id</th>
                              </tr>
                           </thead>

                            <tbody>
                            <?php do { ?>
                              <tr>
                                <td class="try"><?php echo ++$i;?></td>
                                <td class="pid"><?php echo $row_products['pid']; ?></td>
                                <td class="brand"><?php echo $row_products['brand']; ?></td>
                                <td class="model"><?php echo $row_products['model']; ?></td>
                                <td class="item"><?php echo $row_products['item_name_']; ?></td>
                                <td class="price"><?php echo $row_products['price'];?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row_products['id']; ?></td>
                              </tr>
                              <?php } while ($row_products = mysql_fetch_assoc($products)); ?>
                            </tbody>
                         </table>
```

js:

```
$('tbody tr').on('click', function () {



    if (!$(this).hasClass("selected")) {
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        $('#try').append("<p class='try_" + $(this).find('.try').text()+"'>" + $(this).find('.try').text() + "</p>");
        $('#price').append("<p class='try_" + $(this).find('.try').text() + " total'>" + $(this).find('.price').text() + "</p>");
        $('#item').append("<p class='try_" + $(this).find('.try').text() + "'>" + $(this).find('.item').text() + "</p>");
        $('#model').append("<p class='try_" + $(this).find('.try').text() + "'>" + $(this).find('.model').text() + "</p>");
        $('#brand').append("<p class='try_" + $(this).find('.try').text() + "'>" + $(this).find('.brand').text() + "</p>");
        $('#pid').append("<p class='try_" + $(this).find('.try').text() + "'>" + $(this).find('.pid').text() + "</p>");
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        $(".container").find('p').remove(".try_" + $(this).find('.try').text());
    }


});
```

jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/rbrx0obz/

Comment: where  the  values in div?? i want to do is get the value of row. bring it to the div.